# volume inside a solid solid angle

Tags: geometry, spheres, solid-angle

Is it right to say that in a sphere of radius R, the volume inside a solid angle $\Omega$ is just : $V=\frac{4\pi R^3}{3}\frac{\Omega}{4\pi}=\frac{R^3 \Omega}{3}$ ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in another way we can see that the [volume of a spherical sector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_sector#Volume) of radius $r$ is
$$
V=\frac{rA}{3}
$$
where $A$ is the area of the cap that is $A=\Omega r^2$