# Proportion of regular tetrahedron occupied by mutually tangent balls centred at its vertices

Tags: volume, spheres, solid-geometry, platonic-solids

The centres of four balls of radius $1$ are the vertices of a regular tetrahedron of side length $2$. What is the proportion of the tetrahedron occupied by the balls?

At first I thought it should just be the [maximum packing density of spheres](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/KeplerConjecture.html), $\frac{\pi}{3\sqrt2}\approx 0.74048$, but this is not true, because [regular tetrahedrons do not tile space](https://www.ams.org/notices/201211/rtx121101540p.pdf).

I considered the fact that the sphere [kissing number](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/KissingNumber.html) is $12$, but it seems this fact would only be useful if regular tetrahedrons tiled space.

Comment: You just need the solid angle of a regular tetrahedron: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RegularTetrahedron.html

Comment: @Intelligentipauca Thanks. Just to confirm: the solid angle is $\arccos(\frac{23}{27})$, so the volume inside the tetrahedron occupied by one ball is $\frac{1}{4\pi}\arccos(\frac{23}{27})\times\frac{4\pi}{3}$. The volume of the tetrehedron is $\frac{\sqrt2}{12}\times 8^3$. So the answer to my question is $\sqrt2 \arccos(\frac{23}{27})\approx 0.7796$. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, you just wrote $8^3$ instead of $2^3$, but the final result is right.

Comment: @Dan: You could write that up as an answer and accept it so the question doesn't remain unanswered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [solid angle](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RegularTetrahedron.html) of a regular tetrahedron is arccos(2327), so the [volume inside](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3032927/398708) the tetrahedron occupied by one ball is $\frac{1}{4\pi}\arccos\left(\frac{23}{27}\right)\times\frac{4\pi}{3}$. The [volume of the tetrehedron](https://byjus.com/regular-tetrahedron-formula/) is $\frac{\sqrt2}{12}\times 2^3$. So the answer to the question is $\sqrt2 \arccos(\frac{23}{27})\approx 0.7796$.